# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy-save to see them

Tags: networking, iptables

I am calling some iptables rules from a docker container that runs with `NET_ADMIN` which means iptables commands from the container are applied on the host (yes, I need them this way).

When checking the host with `iptables-save` I see no rules being added but I also see a `Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy-save to see them` and, when running `iptables-legacy-save` I can see my rules that are set by the container.

My question is as follows. Are these rules active even if present in the legacy table? Can I do something better?

Container is alpine 3.15, host is debian 10 Buster. Ideally I would want this container to be able to run on ubuntu and debian, regardless of versions.

Comment: Check this so you understand what's the matter: https://wiki.debian.org/iptables#Current_status